# issue with validating form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through all input text fields in form using jquery's each. There are total of 4 input fields. But I am getting following error

```
Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined in jquery.js:2153
```

Here is my code

```
loadViews: function (view, flag) {
            if( flag ) {
                if ( View.validate() ) {
                    $('.search').animate({left: '-350px'}, 100, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
                        container.empty().load(view + '.html');
                    });
                } else {

                }
            } else {
                container.empty().load(view + '.html');
            }
        },
        validate: function () {
            $.each('#form input[type="text"]', function (i) {
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
            return false;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `View.validate()` supposed to be `view.validate()`?

Comment: maybe it's because `View.validate()` (capital _V_) should be `view.validate()`instead?

Comment: No it is correct. v should be V. I mean capital V

Comment: When I use `$(this)` in console then it returns `String` object. Why does it return String. But I want input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a `selector` when [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) expects a collection. From the API docs:

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each()
>   function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is a
>   map (JavaScript object) or an array.

To fix it, do this:

```
$('#form input[type="text"]').each(function (i, elem) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

or this:

```
var inputs = $('#form input[type="text"]');
$.each(inputs, function (i, elem) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```